# Работа со списком объектов созданного класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Необходимо из списка удалить одинаковые элементы, но дело в том, что это не просто числа или символы, а объекты моего класса. Есть класс `Chromosome`:

```
class Chromosome:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.genes = convert_to_binary(val)
        self.decimal = val
        self.fitness = 0
```

Глобально в нём 3 поля: `genes[]` - массив бинарного представления десятичного числа, а `fitness` - это значение функции от десятичного числа. После добавления в список объектов, новый необходимо проверять на наличие похожего эл-та. ИМЕННО по массиву `self.genes`. Хочу реализовать вот что: если в списке окажется несколько (больше 1-го) эл-та с одинаковым массивом (полное соответствие по всем позициям), то необходимо оставлять только один такой эл-т.

P.S. Важное уточнение: размерность массива `genes[]` фиксированная.

Исходные данные - список объектов класса Chromosome

```
Chromosome # 0  : [0, 1, 0, 1] | Fitness:  30
Chromosome # 1  : [0, 1, 1, 0] | Fitness:  29
Chromosome # 2  : [0, 1, 1, 1] | Fitness:  26
Chromosome # 3  : [1, 0, 0, 1] | Fitness:  14
Chromosome # 4  : [0, 0, 0, 0] | Fitness:  5
Chromosome # 5  : [1, 0, 1, 0] | Fitness:  5
Chromosome # 6  : [1, 1, 0, 1] | Fitness:  -34
Chromosome # 7  : [1, 1, 1, 0] | Fitness:  -51
```

Как сделать так что если список имеет вид, то один из элементов (2 или 3) необходимо удалить из списка ?

```
Chromosome # 0  : [0, 1, 0, 1] | Fitness:  30
Chromosome # 1  : [0, 1, 1, 0] | Fitness:  29

Chromosome # 2  : [1, 0, 0, 1] | Fitness:  14
Chromosome # 3  : [1, 0, 0, 1] | Fitness:  14

Chromosome # 4  : [0, 0, 0, 0] | Fitness:  5
Chromosome # 5  : [1, 0, 1, 0] | Fitness:  5
Chromosome # 6  : [1, 1, 0, 1] | Fitness:  -34
Chromosome # 7  : [1, 1, 1, 0] | Fitness:  -51
```

Comment: Представили бы в вопросе ваши данные и что хотели бы в результате. А то непонятно что такое val, что вернет convert_to_binary, где вы хотели дубликаты проверять, по какому признаку дубликаты ищутся и т.п.

Answer (score 5):

По умолчанию в питоне объекты сравниваются по их адресу в памяти. Поэтому два объекта всегда считаются неравными (если только вы не сравниваете объект сам с собой).

Чтобы можно было нормально сравнивать объекты по некоторому их полю, нужно определить для класса специальный метод `__eq__`.

А если кроме него вы ещё определите и метод `__hash__`, то вы сможете помещать ваши объекты в `set` и удаление дублирующихся объектов станет вообще тривиальной задачей.

```
class Chromosome:

    def __init__(self,val):
        self.genes = convert_to_binary(val)
        self.decimal = val
        self.fitness = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.genes == other.genes

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(tuple(self.genes))

chromosomes = [
    Chromosome([0, 1, 0, 1]),
    Chromosome([1, 0, 0, 1]),
    Chromosome([1, 0, 0, 1]),
]

print(set(chromosomes))  # выведет на печать только два объекта, без дублей
```

Comment: Сразу в избранное.